# Python + Pandas + dataframe : couldn't append one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two big CSV files. I have converted them to Pandas dataframes. Both of them have columns of same names and in same order : event_name, category, category_id, description. I want to append one dataframe to another, and, finally want to write the resultant dataframe to a CSV. I wrote a code for that:

```
 #appendind a new dataframe to the older dataframe
 data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
 data1 = pd.read_csv("dataset_new.csv")
 dfs = [data, data1]
 pd.concat([df.squeeze() for df in dfs], ignore_index=True)
 dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns=['event_name','category',  'category_id', 'description'])
 dfs.to_csv('dataset_append.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I wanted to show you the output of `print(dfs)` but I couldn't because Stackoverflow is showing following error because the output is too long:

```
Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 32132.
```

Would you please tell me a code snippet which you use succesfully 
to append Pandas dataframe?

**Edit1:**

```
print(dfs)
```

outout:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
[     Unnamed: 10 Unnamed: 100 Unnamed: 101 Unnamed: 102 Unnamed: 103  \
0            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
2            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
3            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
4            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
5            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
6            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
7            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
8            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
9            NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
10           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
11           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
12           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
13           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
14           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
15           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
16           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
17           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
18           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
19           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
20           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
21           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
22           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
23           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
24           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
25           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
26           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
27           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
28           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
29           NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
...          ...          ...          ...          ...          ...   

1159         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1160         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1161         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1162         NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   

     Unnamed: 104 Unnamed: 105 Unnamed: 106 Unnamed: 107 Unnamed: 108  \
0             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
2             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
3             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
4             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
5             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
6             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
7             NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
...           ...          ...          ...          ...          ...   


1161          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   
1162          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN   

                            ...                         Unnamed: 94  \
0                           ...                                 NaN   
1                           ...                                 NaN   
2                           ...                                 NaN   
3                           ...                                 NaN   
4                           ...                                 NaN   
5                           ...                                 NaN   
6                           ...                                 NaN   
7                           ...                                 NaN   
8                           ...                                 NaN   
9                           ...                                 NaN   
10                          ...                                 NaN   
11                          ...                                 NaN   
12                          ...                                 NaN   
13                          ...                                 NaN   
14                          ...                                 NaN   
15                          ...                                 NaN   
16                          ...                                 NaN   
17                          ...                                 NaN   
18                          ...                                 NaN   
19                          ...                                 NaN   
20                          ...                                 NaN   
21                          ...                                 NaN   
22                          ...                                 NaN   
23                          ...                                 NaN   
24                          ...                                 NaN   
25                          ...                                 NaN   
26                          ...                                 NaN   
27                          ...                                 NaN   
28                          ...                                 NaN   
29                          ...                                 NaN   
...                         ...                                 ...   
1133                        ...                                 NaN   
1134                        ...                                 NaN   
1135                        ...                                 NaN   
1136                        ...                                 NaN   
1137                        ...                                 NaN   
1138                        ...                                 NaN   
1139                        ...                                 NaN   
1140                        ...                                 NaN   
1141                        ...                                 NaN   
1142                        ...                                 NaN   
1143                        ...                                 NaN   
1144                        ...                                 NaN   
1145                        ...                                 NaN   
1146                        ...                                 NaN   
1147                        ...                                 NaN   
1148                        ...                                 NaN   
1149                        ...                                 NaN   
1150                        ...                                 NaN   
1151                        ...                                 NaN   
1152                        ...                                 NaN   
1153                        ...                                 NaN   
1154                        ...                                 NaN   
1155                        ...                                 NaN   
1156                        ...                                 NaN   
1157                        ...                                 NaN   
1158                        ...                                 NaN   
1159                        ...                                 NaN   
1160                        ...                                 NaN   
1161                        ...                                 NaN   
1162                        ...                                 NaN   

     Unnamed: 95 Unnamed: 96 Unnamed: 97 Unnamed: 98 Unnamed: 99  \
0            NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1            NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
2            NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
3            NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
4            NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   

...          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
1133         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1134         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1135         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
1136         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   


                     category category_id  \
0                    Business           2   
1                 stage shows          33   
2                  Literature          15   
3        Science & Technology          22   
4                      health          11   
5        Science & Technology          22   
6                     Outdoor          19   
7                 stage shows          33   
8                   nightlife          30   
9         fashion & lifestyle           6   
10      Government & Activism          25   
11                stage shows          33   
12    Religion & Spirituality          21   
13                    Outdoor          19   
14                 management          17   
15       Science & Technology          22   
16                  nightlife          30   
17                    Outdoor          19   
18              FAMILy & kids           5   
19        fashion & lifestyle           6   
20              FAMILy & kids           5   
21                      games          10   
22                    hobbies          32   
23                    hobbies          32   
24    Religion & Spirituality          21   
25                     health          11   
26        fashion & lifestyle           6   
27         career & education          31   
28                     health          11   
29                       arts           1   
...                       ...         ...   
1133         Sports & Fitness          23   
1134         Sports & Fitness          23   
1135         Sports & Fitness          23   
1136         Sports & Fitness          23   
1137         Sports & Fitness          23   
1138         Sports & Fitness          23   
1139         Sports & Fitness          23   
1140         Sports & Fitness          23   
1141         Sports & Fitness          23   
1142         Sports & Fitness          23   
1143         Sports & Fitness          23   
1144         Sports & Fitness          23   
1145         Sports & Fitness          23   
1146         Sports & Fitness          23   
1147         Sports & Fitness          23   
1148         Sports & Fitness          23   
1149         Sports & Fitness          23   
1150         Sports & Fitness          23   
1151         Sports & Fitness          23   
1152         Sports & Fitness          23   
1153         Sports & Fitness          23   
1154         Sports & Fitness          23   
1155         Sports & Fitness          23   
1156         Sports & Fitness          23   
1157         Sports & Fitness          23   
1158         Sports & Fitness          23   
1159         Sports & Fitness          23   
1160         Sports & Fitness          23   
1161         Sports & Fitness          23   
1162         Sports & Fitness          23   

                                            description  \
0     Josh Talks in partnership with Facebook is all...   
1     Unwind on the strums of Guitar &  immerse your...   
2     Book review for grade 3 and above learners. 3 ...   
3     ..About Organizer:.This is the official page f...   
4     Blood Donation is organized under the banner o...   
5     A day "Etched with Innovation and Learning" to...   
6     Our next destination for Fun with us is "Goa" ...   
7     Enjoy the Soulful and Unplugged Performance of...   
8     Get ready with your dance shoes on as our favo...   
9     FESTIVE HUES -- a fashion and lifestyle exhibi...   
10    On Aug. 8, Dr. Ambedkar presides over the Depr...   
11    It's A Rapper Boys..And M Write A New Rap song...   
12    The Spiritual Makeover..A weekend workshop tha...   
13    Our next destination for Fun with us is "Goa" ...   
14    Project Management is all about getting the th...   
15    World Conference Next Generation Testing 2018 ...   
16    ..About Organizer:.Whitefield is now #Sherlocked!   
17    On occasion of 72th Independence Day , Udaan O...   
18    *Smilofy Special Superstar*.A Talent hunt for ...   
19    ITEEHA is coming back to Bengaluru, after a fa...   
20    This is an exciting course for kids to teach t...   
21    ..About Organizer:.PPG Lounge is a next genera...   
22    Touch Feel Try & Buy the latest #car and #bike...   
23    Sniper Media is organising an exclusive semina...   
24    He has all sorts of powers and able solve any ...   
25    registration fee 50/â‚¹  we r providing free c...   
26    World Biggest Pageant Miss & Mrs World Queen a...   
27    ..About Organizer:.Canam Consultants - India's...   
28    Innopharm is an effort to bring innovations in...   
29    The first Central India Art and Design Expo - ...   
...                                                 ...   
1133  As the cricket fever grips the country again, ...   
1134  An evening of fun, food, drinks and rooting fo...   
1135  The time has come, who will take their place S...   
1136  Do you want to prove that Age is not a barrier...   
1137  We Invite All The Corporate Companies To Be A ...   
1138  PlayTM happy to announce you that conducting o...   
1139  A Mix of fun rules and cricketing skills. Afte...   
1140  Shuttle Swap presents Singles, Doubles and Mix...   
1141  Yonex Mavis 350 Shuttle will be used State/Nat...   
1142  Light up the FIFA World Cup with Bud90 Match S...   
1143  We are charmed to launch the SVSEVENTZ.COM 5-A...   
1144  We corephysio FC invite you for our first foot...   
1145  After completing the 2nd season of Bangalore S...   
1146  As the cricket fever grips the country again, ...   
1147  Introducing BOX Cricket Super 6 Corporate Cric...   
1148  After the sucess of '1st Matt & Mudd T20 Leagu...   
1149  Hi All, It is my pleasure to officially announ...   
1150  Sign up: Get early updates, free movie voucher...   
1151  About VIVO Pro Kabaddi 2018: A new season of t...   
1152  The Hero Indian Super League (ISL) is India's ...   
1153  Limited time offer: Free Paytm Movie Voucher w...   
1154  The 5th edition of the Indian Super League is ...   
1155  Calling all Jamshedpur FC fans! Here's your ch...   
1156  Empower yourself and progress towards a health...   
1157  Making people happy when they feel that its en...   
1158  LOVE YOGA ?- but too busy with work during the...   
1159  The coolest way to tour the city ! Absorb the ...   
1160  Ready to be a part of India's Biggest Walkatho...   
1161  The event will comprise of the following Open ...   
1162  RUN FOR CANCER CHILDREN On world Cancer Day 3r...   

                                             event_name  
0                             Josh Talks Hyderabad 2018  
1                        Guitar Night With Ashmik Patil  
2                         Book Review - August 2018 - 2  
3                                               Csaw'18  
4                                   Blood donation camp  
5     Rajasthan Youth Innovation and Technical Intel...  
6               Goa â€“ Fun All the Way!!! - Mom N Kids  
7     The AnshUdhami Project LIVE at Tales & Spirits...  
8                         Friday Fiesta featuring Pearl  
9                                          FESTIVE HUES  
10                                               Nagpur  
11                             Yo Yo Deep SP The Rapper  
12                               The Spiritual Makeover  
13          Goa Fun All the Way - Women Only group Tour  
14                  MS Project 2016 - A one day seminar  
15             World Conference Next Generation Testing  
16                         Weekend Booster - Happy Hour  
17    Ladies Only Camping : Freedom To Travel (Seaso...  
18                                    Special superstar  
19                             Malaysian Batik Workshop  
20                   EQ Enhancement Course (5-10 years)  
21                         CS:GO Tournament 2018 - PPGL  
22                 Auto Mall at Mantri Square Bangalore  
23    A Seminar by Ojas Rajani (Bollywood celebrity ...  
24    rishikesh katti greatest Spirituality guru of ...  
25                    free BMD camp held on 26 jan 2018  
26    Miss and Mrs Bhopal Madhya Pradesh India World...  
27        USA, Canada & Singapore Application Days 2018  
28                                          Innopharm 3  
29                      Kalasrishti Art and Design Expo  
...                                                 ...  
1133  Asia cup live screening at la casa Brewery+ ki...  
1134  Asia Cup 2018 live screening at La Casa Brewer...  
1135  FIFA FINAL AT KORAMANGALA TETTO - With #fifa#f...  
1136              Womenasia Indoor Cricket Championship  
1137            Switch Hit Corporate Cricket Tournament  
1138             PlayTM Sports Arena Box Cricket league  
1139  The Box Cricket League Edition II (16-17-18 No...  
1140  Shuttle Swap Badminton Tournament - With Singl...  
1141             SPARK BADMINTON LEAGUE - OCT 14th 2018  
1142                   Bud90 Match Screenings at Loft38  
1143                       5 A-Side Football Tournament  
1144  5 vs 5 Football league - With Back 2 Track events  
1145  Bangalore Sports Carnival Table Tennis Juniors...  
1146  Asia cup live screening at la casa Brewery+ ki...  
1147                   Super 6 Corporate Cricket League  
1148  Coolulu is organizing MATT & MUD T20 Cricket L...  
1149    United Sportzs Pure Corporate Cricket season-10  
1150  Sign up for updates on the VIVO Pro Kabaddi Se...  
1151  VIVO Pro Kabaddi - UP Yoddha vs Patna Pirates ...  
1152  HERO Indian Super League 2018-19: Kerala Blast...  
1153                       HERO ISL: FC Goa Memberships  
1154  Hero Indian Super League 2018-19: Delhi Dynamo...  
1155  HERO Indian Super League 2018-19: Jamshedpur F...  
1156                  Yoga Therapy Classes in Bangalore  
1157                                    Saree Walkathon  
1158             Weekend Yoga Teachers Training Program  
1159                                    Bangalore Walks  
1160                        Oxfam Trailwalker Bengaluru  
1161       TAD Pune 2018 (Triathlon Aquathlon Duathlon)  
1162                            RUN FOR CANCER CHILDREN  

[1163 rows x 241 columns],                                             event_name              category  \
0                 Musical Camping at Dahanu Chiku farm               outdoor   
1                            Adventure Camping at Wada               outdoor   
2                                    Kaas Plateau Tour               outdoor   
3                  Pawna Lake Camping, kevre, Lonavala               outdoor   
4               Night Trek and Camping at Korigad Fort               outdoor   
5                                         PARAMOTORING               outdoor   
6    WATERFALL TREK & BEACH CAMPING (NAGALAPURAM: N...               outdoor   
7                      Happiest Land On Earth - Bhutan               outdoor   
8    4 Days serial hiking in Sahyadris - Sep 29 to ...               outdoor   
9                                     Ride To Valparai               outdoor   
10     Dzongri Trek - Gateway to Kanchenjunga Mountain               outdoor   
11                  Skandagiri Night Trek With Camping               outdoor   
12                  Kalsubai Trek | Plan The Unplanned               outdoor   
13                              Bike N Hike Skandagiri               outdoor   
14        Unplanned Stories - Episode 6 - Travel Tales               outdoor   
15                Feast on authentic flavors from Goa!               outdoor   
16                                       The Boot Camp               outdoor   
17   The HandleBards: Romeo and Juliet at Ranga Sha...               outdoor   
18   Workshop on Metagenomic Sequencing on the Grid...  Science & Technology   
19                                          Aerovision  Science & Technology   
20                Electric Vehicle Technology Workshop  Science & Technology   
21                                 BPM Strategy Summit  Science & Technology   
22         Summit of Interior Designers & Architecture  Science & Technology   
23                       SMART ASIA India Expo& Summit  Science & Technology   
24                        A Smart City Life Exhibition  Science & Technology   
25                                   OPEN SOURCE INDIA  Science & Technology   
26                          SolarRoofs India Bangalore  Science & Technology   
27   International Conference on Innovative Researc...  Science & Technology   
28   International Conference on Business Managemen...  Science & Technology   
29    DevOn Summit Bangalore - Digital Transformations  Science & Technology   
..                                                 ...                   ...   
144  Asia cup live screening at la casa Brewery+ ki...      Sports & Fitness   
145  Asia Cup 2018 live screening at La Casa Brewer...      Sports & Fitness   
146  FIFA FINAL AT KORAMANGALA TETTO - With #fifa#f...      Sports & Fitness   
147              Womenasia Indoor Cricket Championship      Sports & Fitness   
148            Switch Hit Corporate Cricket Tournament      Sports & Fitness   
149             PlayTM Sports Arena Box Cricket league      Sports & Fitness   
150  The Box Cricket League Edition II (16-17-18 No...      Sports & Fitness   
151  Shuttle Swap Badminton Tournament - With Singl...      Sports & Fitness   
152             SPARK BADMINTON LEAGUE - OCT 14th 2018      Sports & Fitness   
153                   Bud90 Match Screenings at Loft38      Sports & Fitness   
s   
170                                    Bangalore Walks      Sports & Fitness   
171                        Oxfam Trailwalker Bengaluru      Sports & Fitness   
172       TAD Pune 2018 (Triathlon Aquathlon Duathlon)      Sports & Fitness   
173                            RUN FOR CANCER CHILDREN      Sports & Fitness   

     category_id                                        description  \
0             19  Dear All Camping Lovers, Come take camping exp...   
1             19  Our Adventure campsite at Wada is developed wi...   
2             19  Type: Eco Tour Height: 3937 FT above MSL (Appr...   
3             19  Our Pawna Lake Camping site is located near Ke...   
4             19  Type: Hill Fort Height: 3050 Feet above MSL (A...   

23            22  Making 'Smart Cities Mission' a Reality The SM...   
24            22  A Smart City Life A Smart City Life Exhibition...   
25            22  Asia's No. 1 Convention on Open Source Started...   
26            22  The conference will offer an excellent platfor...   
27            22  Provides a leading forum for the presentation ...   
28            22  Provide opportunity for the global participant...   
29            22  The biggest event about Digital Transformation...   
..           ...                                                ...   
144           23  As the cricket fever grips the country again, ...   
145           23  An evening of fun, food, drinks and rooting fo...   
146           23  The time has come, who will take their place S...   
147           23  Do you want to prove that Age is not a barrier...   
148           23  We Invite All The Corporate Companies To Be A ...   
149           23  PlayTM happy to announce you that conducting o...   
150           23  A Mix of fun rules and cricketing skills. Afte...   
151           23  Shuttle Swap presents Singles, Doubles and Mix...   
152           23  Yonex Mavis 350 Shuttle will be used State/Nat...   
153           23  Light up the FIFA World Cup with Bud90 Match S...   
154           23  We are charmed to launch the SVSEVENTZ.COM 5-A...   
155           23  We corephysio FC invite you for our first foot...   
156           23  After completing the 2nd season of Bangalore S...   
157           23  As the cricket fever grips the country again, ...   
158           23  Introducing BOX Cricket Super 6 Corporate Cric...   
159           23  After the sucess of '1st Matt & Mudd T20 Leagu...   
160           23  Hi All, It is my pleasure to officially announ...   
161           23  Sign up: Get early updates, free movie voucher...   
162           23  About VIVO Pro Kabaddi 2018: A new season of t...   
163           23  The Hero Indian Super League (ISL) is India's ...   
164           23  Limited time offer: Free Paytm Movie Voucher w...   
165           23  The 5th edition of the Indian Super League is ...   
166           23  Calling all Jamshedpur FC fans! Here's your ch...   
167           23  Empower yourself and progress towards a health...   
168           23  Making people happy when they feel that its en...   
169           23  LOVE YOGA ?- but too busy with work during the...   
170           23  The coolest way to tour the city ! Absorb the ...   
171           23  Ready to be a part of India's Biggest Walkatho...   
172           23  The event will comprise of the following Open ...   
173           23  RUN FOR CANCER CHILDREN On world Cancer Day 3r...   

    Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5  
0          NaN        NaN  
1          NaN        NaN  
2          NaN        NaN  
3          NaN        NaN  
4          NaN        NaN  

24         NaN        NaN  
25         NaN        NaN  
26         NaN        NaN  
27         NaN        NaN  
28         NaN        NaN  
29         NaN        NaN  
..         ...        ...  
144        NaN        NaN  
145        NaN        NaN  
146        NaN        NaN  
147        NaN        NaN  
148        NaN        NaN  
149        NaN        NaN  


[174 rows x 6 columns]]
```

Comment: What error do you get from python/pandas?

Comment: No error. Let me find a way to show you the content of the resultant dataframe.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ or use a paste-bin type website

Comment: @Rich : I shortened the output and pasted. Plz see once.

Comment: How many columns are there in each df?

Comment: can you paste the output of 'describe' and 'shape' function for data and data1?

Comment: my guess would be that the CSVs have been saved from Excel and have dozens of blank columns at the end of each row

Comment: @yuca : Basically they should have 4 columns as I mentioned in my problem explanation. But the 'description' portion is usually too long to fit into the field space of a column. I am not sure though.

Comment: @Debbie the output led me to believe you had more than a hundred, despite your description of the problem. Since we can't replicate your conditions, I would suggest you work with only your first 5 rows of data on each dataframe. The squeeze is highly suspicious by the way

Comment: This can't be your working code. You do not assign `pd.concat` to anything and as shown *dfs* is an empty data frame with named columns. So CSV output should have empty named columns.

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with a simple:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)).to_csv('File.csv', index=False)
```

this will work if they have the **same columns**.

A more verbose way to extract specific columns would be:

```
(pd.concat([df1[['event_name','category',  'category_id', 'description']], 
df2[['event_name','category',  'category_id', 'description']]], 
ignore_index=True))
.to_csv('File.csv', index=False))
```

Separate Notes:

1. you are initializing a DF with just columns and then outputting that to a CSV.
2. Why are you using `.squeeze` to convert it to 1-D dataset?