# append one dataframe column value to another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes. df1 is empty dataframe and df2 is having some data as shown. There are few columns common in both dfs. I want to append df2 dataframe columns data into df1 dataframe's column. df3 is expected result.

I have referred [Python + Pandas + dataframe : couldn't append one dataframe to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667035/python-pandas-dataframe-couldnt-append-one-dataframe-to-another), but not working. It gives following error:
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned

df1:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d, e]
Index: [] `
```

df2:

```
    c   e
0  11  55
1  22  66
```

df3 (expected output):

```
  a b   c d   e
0      11    55
1      22    66
```

tried with append but not getting desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
l2 = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=l1)


l3 = ['c', 'e']
l4 = [[11, 55],
      [22, 66]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l4, columns=l3)



print("concat","\n",pd.concat([df1,df2]))  # columns will be inplace

print("merge Nan","\n",pd.merge(df2, df1,how='left', on=l3))  # columns occurence is not preserved


#### Output  ####
#concat 
      a    b   c    d   e
0  NaN  NaN  11  NaN  55
1  NaN  NaN  22  NaN  66

#merge
     c   e    a    b    d
0  11  55  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  22  66  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Yes, this serves the purpose. What if, we want to append df2 data in existing data frame which already contains some data.

Comment: Depending on the specific requirements you can either concat, merge, append or even join function as well. This may help you [Merge_Join_Concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

Answer (score 1):

Append seems to work for me. Does this not do what you want?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print("df1: ")
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'c'], data=[[0, 1], [2, 3]])
print("df2:")
print(df2)
print("df1.append(df2):")
print(df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True, sort=False))
```

Output:

```
df1: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
df2:
   a  c
0  0  1
1  2  3
df1.append(df2):
   a    b  c
0  0  NaN  1
1  2  NaN  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `pd.concat` ?

`pd.concat([df1,df2])`